# Azure ATP sensor : Could not create SSL/TLS secure channel

Tags: azure

I have multiple DC on which Azure ATP sensor is working fine, however on one of Domain controller 2008 R2 server it is throwing below error

Error ExceptionHandler Microsoft.Tri.Infrastructure.ExtendedException: RestrictCpuAsync failed, exiting ---> System.Net.Http.HttpRequestException: An error occurred while sending the request. ---> System.Net.WebException: The request was aborted: Could not create SSL/TLS secure channel.

Could you please advise, installation is having no issues

Microsoft.Tri.Sensor-Errors - shows above logs

Comment: Is this the only DC Server 2008 R2 or you have others? It will be advisable to update to a newer server OS. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/defender-for-identity/prerequisites